# Как получить количество реально "используемых" битов?

Tags: java

Например, `int` 32-битно, но у нас есть там... `230`, это `11100110` остальные 24 бита это не значащие нули, так вот нет ли возможности их отсечь и получить именно количество которое припадает на число?

Comment: Уточните, вас интересуют только целые положительные числа, или отрицательные и дробные тоже?

Comment: Положительные и отрицательные
(дроби тоже было бы хорошо, но всего понемногу, думаю пока разобраться с целыми числа)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class BitsDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int value = 230;
        System.out.println(Integer.SIZE - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(value));
    }
}
```